# Yii: Data Caching on other actions

Tags: php, caching, yii, twitter

I have an app which links twitter to it with the API, in this action I have a creation of a request key which is done here:

```
 public function createRequestKey()
 {
     $this->setScenario(self::SCENARIO_DEFAULT);
     if (!$this->validate())
         return false;

     $cache = \Yii::app()->cache;
     $key = __CLASS__ . '_' . $this->user->id . '_' . time() . '_' . rand(0, 100);
     $key = sha1($key);
     $data = array(
         'userId' => $this->user->id,      
     );
     $cache->set($key, $data, 60 * 30);
     $this->requestKey = $key;
     return true;
 }
```

The action that calls this method is this:

```
 public function actionTwitterLinkUrl()
 {
    if (!$this->checkOAuthRequest())
        return;

    $request  = \Yii::app()->getRequest();
    $response = \Yii::app()->response->setContentTypeToJSON();

    $user = $this->getUserFromHeader();
    $this->matchUserToLastValidatedToken($user);

    $linker = new \Sakanade\Operations\APITwitterLinker($user);
    if ($linker->createRequestKey()) {
        $params = $this->createQueryStringParams($linker->requestKey);
        $response->set('type',UserProfile::profileTypeToString(UserProfile::PROFILETYPE_TWITTER))
                 ->set('url', $request->getBaseUrl(true) . '/users/' . urlencode($user->id)
                 . '/profiles/twitter/link?' . http_build_query($params));
    } else {
        $response->setStatusCode(\Harusame\Components\HttpResponse::STATUS_BAD_REQUEST)
                 ->addMessage(\Sakanade\Models\Model::flattenErrorMessages($linker));
    }

    $response->render();
 }
```

But upon calling the next action, if I access the cache using $cache->get($key) it returns to false, even though it set the cache's storage time of about 1800 seconds.

```
public function actionTwitterRunLink()
{
    $request = \Yii::app()->request;
    $requestKey = $request->getQuery('key');
    if (!$this->checkOAuthRequest())
        return;

    $user = $this->getUserFromHeader();
    $this->matchUserToLastValidatedToken($user);

    $authUrl = $this->getAuthorizationUrl($user);
    $response = \Yii::app()->response->setContentTypeToJSON();
    $cache = \Yii::app()->cache;
    $response->set('key', $cache->get($requestKey))
             ->set('key2', $requestKey);
    $response->render();
}
```

Upon displaying the rendered key from the cache it returns to false but if I try to get it from the previous action there is a returned value. Why is the cache cleared upon calling another action? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A bit less unrelated code and your cache config would be helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If im not mistaken cache time if not referenced from 'now'
I think it should be :

```
$cache->set($key, $data, time() + (60 * 30));
```